# onclick event of dataTables not working after binding data using ajax

Tags: ajax, datatables

I have a datatable which will be model binded when the page opens but when i am doing any edit or delete function the the datatable will be binded using ajax call. So I am having a function

```
 $('#user-detail-datatable tbody tr td a').on('click', function () {

        //prepoluting values on edit
        $("#CarryUser").val($(this).closest('tr').find('td')[5].outerText);
        d = $(this).closest('tr').find('a')[1].id;
        $("#display").val($(this).closest('tr').find('td')[6].outerText);
        UsingBranchId = $(this).closest('tr').find('td')[2].outerText;
        $("#fileUpload").val($(this).closest('tr').find('td')[0].outerText);
    });
```

used to get the values from datatable to bind a model which will open on click of edit button. but this function is not getting hit after I am editing or deleting can anyone explain why. And help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use a [delegated event handler](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). As for now you have one time binding to elements which is lost as soon the table is updated. Use

```js
$('#user-detail-datatable').on('click', 'tbody tr td a', function () {
}]
```

instead.